# Unable to start Tomcat8 because of org.apache.catalina.core.JasperListener?

Tags: windows-server-2003, tomcat, tomcat8, jsp

I cannot start Tomcat8 because of the Jasper Listener, When I start Tomcat8 I got this message:

```
        org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Catalina.start using conf/server.xml: Error at (30, 65) : org.apache.catalina.core.JasperListener
        28-Jun-2017 15:47:19.849 SEVERE [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.startElement Begin event threw exception
        java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.catalina.core.JasperListener
                        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
                        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
                        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
                        at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.ObjectCreateRule.begin(ObjectCreateRule.java:116)
                        at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.startElement(Digester.java:1180)
                        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
                        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(Unknown Source)
                        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
                        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
                        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
                        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
                        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
                        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
                        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
                        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
                        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
                        at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1448)
                        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:552)
                        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:617)
                        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
                        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
                        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
                        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)
                        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)
```

I googled for solutions, but I didn't find anything useful.
Any Help!

Comment: I think the problem are at `conf/server.xml: Error at (30, 65)`

Comment: For the configuration I tried to add jasper listener class and remove this line but the same issue

Comment: Is it the original `server.xml` file or a copy from some previous version?

Comment: Copy from another version, Tomcat 6. But I don't use blind copy I just copy the modules that I will need in Tomcat8

Answer (score 0):

Copy from another version, Tomcat 6. 
But I don't use blind copy I just copy the modules that I will need in Tomcat8